# How to use tuples for a game?

Tags: python

So I am pretty new to Python and I want to create a game (Tic Tac Toe) but I have to use Tuples instead of a list in order to create the game and I don't know how to do it. I have only seen people creating the game with lists so I don't know what I have to do. I'll leave some code and what I wanted to do.

```
board = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]


def draw_board(board):
    print(board[1] + " |" + board[2] + " |" + board[3])
    print("--+--+--")
    print(board[4] + " |" + board[5] + " |" + board[6])
    print("--+--+--")
    print(board[7] + " |" + board[8] + " |" + board[9])
```

This is the normal way and instead of how `board` is written I wanted to create like this:

```
board = (("-","-","-"),("-","-","-"),("-","-","-"))
```

The numbers stay the same, I just don't know how I can use this "as a `list`"
.

Comment: `board[0][0..2]  board[1][0..2]  board[2][0..2]` - same as you would any list of list...

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a tuple containing tuples, you use multi indexing to access the elements, just like a 2-D array:

```
board = (("-","-","-"),("-","-","-"),("-","-","-"))

def draw_board(board):
  print(board[0][0] + " |" + board[0][1] + " |" + board[0][2]) # prints 1st tuple
  print("--+--+--")
  print(board[1][0] + " |" + board[1][1] + " |" + board[1][2]) # prints 2nd tuple
  print("--+--+--")
  print(board[2][0] + " |" + board[2][1] + " |" + board[2][2]) # prints 3rd tuple

draw_board(board)
```

The way the indexing works is: board[row][column]

Comment: Thanks (as you can see I am pretty new, sorry)

Comment: no worries, glad it makes sense!